# What is a one-word synonym for "a piece of wisdom" or "rule of thumb"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking to describe something less formalized--i.e., with a lower collocation--than "aphorism", "maxim" or "adage" would imply. "Dictum" is the closest I can come up with but it's still too dogmatic.

In short, an idea, not an expression.

Comment: You will have to give some examples of what you are hoping to name. I can think of an *adage* but it will be a different piece of advice from a *maxim* or even an *aphorism*. A little help, please.

Comment: There is [**saw³**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/saw). *According to the old **saw**, a language is a dialect with an army and a navy.*

Comment: Maybe [guidepost](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/guidepost) or [guideline](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/guideline) would suffice.

Comment: "A piece of wisdom" and "a rule of thumb" mean different things. I would have said **advice** or **counsel**, but neither explicitly states that it is actually *wise*.